# Issue with Perl Regex

Tags: regex, perl

new perl coder here.

When I copy and paste the text from a website into a text file and read from that file, my perl script works with no issues. When I use getstore to create a file from the website automatically which is what I want, the output is a bunch of |'s.

The text looks identical when I copy and paste, or download the text with getstore.. I'm unable to figure out the problem. Any help would be highly appreciated.

The output that I desire is as follows:

```
|www\.arkinsoftware\.in|www\.askmeaboutrotary\.com|www\.assculturaleincontri\.it|www\.asu\.msmu\.ru|www\.atousoft\.com|www\.aucoeurdelanature\.
enter code here
```

Here is the code I am using:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use LWP::Simple;

getstore("http://www.malwaredomainlist.com/hostslist/hosts.txt",     "malhosts.txt");

open(my $input, "<", "malhosts.txt");

while (my $line = <$input>) {
    chomp $line;
    $line =~ s/.*\s+//;
    $line =~ s/\./\\\./g;
    print "$line\|";
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The bunch of | you get, is from the unfitting comment-lines at the beginning. So the solution is to ignore all "unfitting" lines.

So instead of

```
$line =~ s/.*\s+//;
```

use

```
next unless $line =~ s/^127.*\s+//;
```

so you would ignore every line except thos starting with 127.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I'd do:

```
my $first = 1;
while (<$input>) {
    /^127\.0\.0\.1\s+(.+?)\s*$/ or next;
    print '|' if !$first;
    $first = 0;
    print quotemeta($1);
}
```

This matches your input in a more precise way, and `quotemeta` takes care of true regex escaping.

Answer (score 0):

I'd probably go with something like:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use LWP::Simple;

getstore( "http://www.malwaredomainlist.com/hostslist/hosts.txt",
    "malhosts.txt" );

open( my $input, "<", "malhosts.txt" );

print join ( "|", 
        map { m/^\d/ && ! m/localhost/ ? 
              quotemeta ((split)[1]) : () } <$input> );
```

Gives:

```
0koryu0\.easter\.ne\.jp|1\-atraffickim\.tf|10\-trafficimj\.tf|109\-204\-26\-16\.netconnexion\.managedbroadband\.co\.uk|11\-atraasikim\.tf|11\.lamarianella\.info|12\-tgaffickvcmb\.tf|  #etc.
```